# Can I centralize my app settings in multiple .net core web jobs in Azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, configuration, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-webjobs

I have an Azure web app with several web jobs in the back-end. Up until now, I have been using traditional .Net to create these web jobs. One of the core aspects of these web jobs is that they all access global configuration properties defined in the Azure portal, as shown below:

[image: Global settings for all my Azure web jobs]

And I reference these settings in my traditional .Net app like so:

```
var appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RingCentral_AppKey"];
```

I am now starting to transition my web jobs to .Net Core. However, the "best practice" for for managing/retrieving app settings like this seems to be in an `appsettings.json` file within each web job:

[image]

And I reference my settings in my .Net Core app like so:

```
class Program
{
    public static IConfiguration StaticConfig { get; set; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new HostBuilder();
        builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
        {
            b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
            b.AddAzureStorage();
        });
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
        {
            var conf = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true).Build();
            config.AddConfiguration(conf);
        });
        var host = builder.Build();
        using (host)
        {
            host.Run();
        }
    }
}

public class Functions
{
    IConfiguration configuration;
    public Functions(IConfiguration _configuration)
    {
        configuration = _configuration;
    }
    [NoAutomaticTrigger]
    public void DoTrigger(ILogger logger, [Queue("messagestarterqueue")] ICollector<string> outputQueueMessage)
    {
        var appKey = configuration["RingCentral_AppKey"];
    }
}
```

That's all good, but I have to have a separate `appsettings.config` file in each separate project, each with the same settings repeated. Is there a way to "centralize" theses settings for my .Net Core web jobs? Either create a "global" `appsettings.config` file that my Azure web app can reference? Or, is there some way that each .Net Core app can reference the "old style" application settings that are currently being used by the traditional .Net web jobs?

Comment: If you want centralized configs, you can look at Azure App Config. It will provide a similar experience than what you have now and you can use it with .NET Core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to suggest a bit different approach.
IMHO, the best way you can do it is by utilizing the Azure App Configuration service.
(Check it on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration))

It will allow you to call an API to get the configured values, while you can manage it conveniently through the portal.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'm going to check it out.

Comment: So if you're not using Azure, your screwed?  I'm thinking I may have to move settings to a table in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(your settings key)` to get the settings.

After you set the settings in Configuration, they will be saved as environment variables, you could check them in https://yousitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml.

So of course yo could get them `GetEnvironmentVariable`, it will show as below pic.

[image]

[image]